# lmfit VoigtModel eval() keeps giving exact same values for different parameters set?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have a quick question regarding the `eval()` function for the VoigtModel. I have a few different parameters sets and am trying to evaluate under a set of x values. A simple demonstration is down below. Somehow, no matter what parameter set I use, the `eval()` keeps giving me the same values.

```
from lmfit.models import VoigtModel
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p1={'v0_amplitude': 0.7895507911965995, 'v0_center': 0, 'v0_sigma': 0.3115195639177176, 'v0_gamma': 0.3115195639177176}
p2={'v1_amplitude': 0.2433671058552931, 'v1_center': 0, 'v1_sigma': 0.5154224820790644, 'v1_gamma': -0.10060349484692119}
p3={'v2_amplitude': 0.2560477563760484, 'v2_center': 0, 'v2_sigma': 0.19387399410496087, 'v2_gamma': 0.5953440400428517}

p=[p1, p2, p3]
v1=VoigtModel(prefix='v0_')
v2=VoigtModel(prefix='v1_')
v3=VoigtModel(prefix='v2_')

v = [v1, v2, v3]
x = np.linspace(-10,10, 100)

for i in range(3):
  y = v[i].eval(p[i], x=x)
  plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

what it gives me is exactly three overlapped profiles [figure of three overlapping lineshapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJjrN.png). However, obviously, they all should be different. I am not sure where it really goes wrong. Any help maybe?

Comment: um, why are you passing a dict as the first value of Model.eval()?  Also, why are your dictionary keys named `v1_amplitude`, etct?  Your use case just seems very confused.  Do you mean to evaluate `VoigtModel().eval(amplitude=0.7895, center=0, sigma=0.3115, x=x)`, etc.  If so, your problem is with convincing Python to get those values to the arguments of the `Model.eval()` method.

Comment: Hi @M Newville, this code is just a short demonstration of what I have in hand; the home-built function is a sum of 5 Voigt profiles. Therefore, each of the Voigt profile is prefixed as shown in Example 3 [https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html]. For passing the variables in, if it is not the correct way, is there an easier way to do it? I originally thought it would take a dict as the variable but obviously I am wrong.

Comment: The first argument of VoigtModel.eval() is not a dictionary.  As I said before, you might mean `VoigtModel().eval(amplitude=0.7895, center=0, sigma=0.3115, x=x)`, but `VoigtModel().eval({'p1_amplitude': 0.7895, 'p1_center': 0, 'p1_sigma': 0.3115}, x=x)` is not the correct syntax.   The problem is **not** with lmfit.Model itself, it is how one calls a Python function with keyword arguments.  You might want to refresh you memory on that, and maybe look into the `**kws`  concept.   And: `v1_amplitude` is not a valid keyword argument for `VoigtModel` - you probably mean `amplitude`.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about the type for the first argument and directly fitting in all parameters work. The keyword argument however can be modified with a prefix as in 'VoigtModel(prefix='v0_')' for example.